# Setting hidden field value with special characters using javascript

Tags: jquery, escaping, special-characters, hidden-field, setvalue

I am trying to set the following text "Here's a comment" as value for the hidden field using javascript. But it renders the following output.

```
<input type="hidden" comment"'="" a="" s="" value="1051_"Here" name="comment">
```

I need to get the above text in the MVC controller action on form submit. How do set the above text with special characters as the value for hidden field using JavaScript so that value can be catch as it was sent with special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your input code has misplaced `quote` and `double quote`.

```
<input type="hidden" comment="" a="" s="" value="1051_Here" name="comment">
```

Set value

```
 $("input[name='comment']").val("Here's a comment");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just *escape* the single quote `'` with a backslash `\` like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="comment" name="comment" value="">

$('#comment').val('Here\'s a comment');
```

Here's a jsFiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/vK2a9/